# Kurento iOS room video not shown on iOS 10.3

Tags: ios, objective-c, webrtc, kurento, ios10.3.2

I am using kurento ios code from the url

https://github.com/nubomediaTI/Kurento-iOS

It works perfectly on iOS 9.3.5.

But in iOS 10.3.2 the video stream of peer is not shown, like this (https://github.com/nubomediaTI/Kurento-iOS/issues/33). It shows only the gray screen in my case.

Is anyone know the reason?

Comment: do you have swift samples? thank you

Answer (score 3):

The following steps work on getting streams on IOS 10+ devices.

1.Go to Xcode and open nobomedia project and search this class "NBMPeerViewCell.m".

2.Find "setVideoView" method and uncomment this line  "[self setNeedsLayout];"

```
- (void)setVideoView:(UIView *)videoView {
if (!videoView) {
    [self hideCellSubview:self.videoView];
    return;
}
if (_videoView != videoView) {
    [_videoView removeFromSuperview];
    _videoView = videoView;
    [self.containerViewW insertSubview:_videoView aboveSubview:_peerLabelW];
    [self showCellSubview:_videoView];

    [self setNeedsLayout];
}}
```